# Replacing a mysql table using R code

Tags: r

I am trying to export data from R data frame into mysql table  names X using "sqlsave" function of RODBC. But, as per my process, I need to replace the data everytime in the table X. Can anyone let me know if I can do that inside R to either drop the table and then create an new table using sqlsave or if there is a way to replace the table X with new data.

Thanks!!!

Comment: do you need to overwrite data every time?

Comment: @agstudy: Yes, my process creates new data everyday which I need to write in the table overwriting the previous data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to overwrite table :

The simpler is to use `RMySQL` and `dbWriteTable`.

```
dbWriteTable(connection, data.frame, "MyTable", overwrite = TRUE, row.names = FALSE )
```

PS: if the table doesn't exist , the first call it will be created.